# Messages without a matching method signature will be assume to return id

Tags: iphone, ipad

I'm getting a warning from the compiler :

"warning: 'NSSortDescriptor' may not respond to '+sortDescriptorWithKey:ascending:' "

...on this line of code:

```
id sortDescriptor=[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"value" ascending:YES];
```

the compiler is also saying the following:

"Messages without a matching method signature will be assume to return id..."

+sortDescriptorWithKey:ascending:is a standard method of the platorm.  It's not my own class.

I think this message usually appears when you don't declare the method in the interface but again, this is not my method.

Any ideas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sortDescriptorWithKey:ascending:` method was introduced in iOS 4.0. So it sounds like you are compiling with a *Base SDK* set to something lower than 4.0.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  IOS 4.1 is installed but this is for iPad...iOS 3.2.  Do you have any ideas how to sort a multi-dimensional array with an integer value as the the sort key?  I was trying to accomplish this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626267/sorting-2d-arrays-in-objective-c

Comment: I figured it out...just used the instance method -initWithKey:ascending and it worked fine.